# 3-tier architecture with 3rd integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have a N tier architecture and now I need to add integration with warehouse system.
I created integration and now I can use it like:

```
var provider = IntegrationFactory.GetDataProvider("integration name");
var integrationOrders = await provider.Orders.GetAllAsync();
```

What a problem - I have a service layer that usually works with my DAL like CRUD operation and filling DTO Models.
I have to create method that will SYNC my Orders for example with integration Orders - Let's call this method like "SyncIntegrationOrders" where I'll get all orders from the Integration side and sync them with orders from my database, so I don't really understand **is it possible to keep this method in my OrderService that I use for working with DAL** ?
Or it will break SRP principle...
But anyway I will need DAL layer too when I want to SyncIntegrationOrders...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand that you want to add the method to post data into the DB and you can add one more function in the service layer. So, in your service, there are 2 methods: GET & POST. This should be fine. Please add comment if you think I misunderstood your scenario.

Comment: You can have the sync orders in your orderservice class, it is part of your business logic. Your orderservice class isn't exclusively there just so it can touch the DAL, it is there to interact with all outside sources and apply business rules pertaining to orders. If you had the sync order method in your DAL, that would be wrong.

Comment: @JohanP thanks.
Another question - if I need to send a specific order to integration ?
For example I can get order by id from my database and I need to send it to my integration provider like provider.Orders.Create(orderFromMyDatabase).
Can I still have it inside my OrderService like "SendOrderToIntegration" ?
I worry because other methods usually work with my DAL but this one should send data to integration... it's like other duties

Comment: @AlexKvitchastiy Yes absolutely. Orderservice is the central point to interact with all your different datasources. So it will interact with your db datasource as well as the external datasource i.e. warehouses.

Answer (score 0):

I would not mix sync- and order- services because:

1) sync-service adds some dependencies not related to order-service such as IntegrationFactory, external datasource etc

2) sync-service can have specific features not related to order-service: such as failure recovering, data consistency on remote side, merging orders, resolving merging conflicts etc

3) it eases unit-testing

4) it eases to decomposition of app, for example into microservices

Some remarks:

- sync-service needs sooner to communicate/depend with order-service not DAL otherwise it can duplicate some business logic defined in order-service
- order-service needs sooner do not accept/return DTO, it manipulates the business-entities (DTOs are introduced higher - in Facade or 'Presentation' (such as Controller, ApiController ..))
- decoupling: order-service should just notify the system about some events such as 'order created' etc not call sync-service by itself. Sync-service subscribes on required events and make processing based on its logic (for example, makes batching processing).

Comment: Sync is not a service, it's a method. Orderservice is an orchestration layer, it can get orders from multiple sources and apply business rules. You don't need an orderservice per datasource

Comment: I'm truly appreciate your time and effort but I didn't get your message because I talked about Sync Method inside OrderService :)
As @JohanP says it would be really weird to have particular service because I have synchronizations among orders/products/etc... So I have to add additional service for synchronization per each entity

Comment: @Alex Kvitchastiy - IMHO it is not responsibility *-service to care about sync so appeared new sync-service. I provided my arguments in the answer. Sorry, I don't see something weird to add new sync-service per business entity or introduce one sync-service that manages several [commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: Just some concerns if I right understood problem scope: 1) data consistency - suspect your services 'are covered' transaction but how it be ensured on remoted db? 2) failure resolving - suggest that occurred error and Order isn't synced, is it responsibility of Order-service to tracking this cases and make recovering by schedule/on the next call?

Comment: @vladimir good point, it made me think.

Okay, I can create sync-service per  entity that I need to sync.
But what about other thing that i need to do like this one - For example I can get order by id from my database and I need to send it to my integration provider like provider.Orders.Create(orderFromMyDatabase).
Where should I keep this logic ? Can I keep it in OrderService or it's better to create IntegrationOrderService and do it inside ? But another problem this service can work with my DAL for some reasons like this one above

Comment: I would definitely create a Sync Service who has that responsabiliy. This also looks like a good scenario to use a message queue.